# jshint functions with dots in the name

Tags: javascript, d3.js, jshint, gruntjs

I'm running jshint on a javascript file, and some of the functions have dots in their names (as a way of namespacing). In particular, I'm using the d3 library, and I have a lot of code that looks like

```
d3.select("something")
```

Do I just need to turn off jshint's checking of using undefined variables? Or is there a way to suppress just certain variable names from being checked. I'm using grunt to build the project.

Comment: you should try adding in the first line something like `/*global d3: true*/`. I'm using jshint in aptana and if i use this line for the objects that i know they exist it won't throw any warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrong.

You are calling the `select` method on the `d3` variable.
You're getting a warning because JSHint doesn't know about the `d3` variable.

You need to tell it that the `d3` global has been defined elsewhere, like this:

```
/*global d3:false */
```

The `:false` will tell it to complain if you ever overwrite the global.

Comment: in the d3 source code, there is a definition that looks like   d3.select = function(selector) {...}. Doesn't that indicate the function name is d3.select?

Comment: No.  That assigns a value (which happens to be a function) to the `select` property of the `d3` variable.

Comment: @JeffStorey No, the decimal is syntactic sugar for d3["select"], you are storing the method into d3.

Comment: @JeffStorey d3 is an object, yes.

Comment: I have another library though has a similar function definition - my.somefunc = function(...) {}. Is that creating a "my" variable even if it wasn't created elsewhere?

Comment: @JeffStorey If 'my' is not defined then an error will be thrown. Are you sure it doesn't exist beforehand? You could add an `alert(my);` line before that assignment to test it really quickly.